# Value of type 'String' has no member 'characterAtIndex'

Tags: swift, nsstring

I'm using the following UITextFieldDelegate method:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,
replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
```

and get the error-message above when trying to access the first character:

```
let firstChar = string.characterAtIndex(0)
```

I don't know what's wrong with this code, since the NSString class reference lists the function:

```
func characterAtIndex(_ index: Int) -> unichar
```

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to explicitly bridge (cast) `String` to `NSString`:

```
(string as NSString).characterAtIndex(0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response!

Answer (score 2):

Although Swift's `String` and `NSString` are interchangeable, in the sense that you can pass `String` to APIs expecting `NSString` and vice versa, the two are not the same. Generally, you cannot call `NSString` methods on `String` without a cast.

The way you get the initial character from `String` is different - rather than using `characterAtIndex(0)` you call

```
let str = "Hello"
let initialChar = str[str.startIndex] // will throw when str is empty
```

or

```
let initialChar = str.characters.first // produces an optional value
```

Comment: Possibly worth mentioning that the above yields Swift native type `Character` (unicode extended grapheme clusters), whereas the OP:s `.characterAtIndex(_:)` yields `unichar` (UTF-16 code units); two types that are not trivially exchangeable (I'm doubtful if OP really wants `unichar`, though :). Also, consider using a safer alternative over `str[str.startIndex]` (<-- runtime exception for empty string), e.g. `str.characters.first` with optional binding.

Comment: @dfri Thanks for a great comment!